# Returning currency rate via API Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, converters, bots, api-design, botframework

I am working on a Microsoft Bot Project which will return the  specified currency rate (as compared to NZD).
E.G. User: aud
     Bot: 1.18

The problem I am having is that the code doesn't print out anything (even though the connection is working).
Here is the some of the code that I have:

```
            double aud = rootObject.rates.AUD;
            double inr = rootObject.rates.INR;
            double jpy = rootObject.rates.JPY;
            double eur = rootObject.rates.EUR;
            double gbp = rootObject.rates.GBP;

            string[] array = new string[]
                {"aud", "inr", "jpy", "eur", "gbp"};

           foreach(string i in array)
            {
                if (ActivityTypes.Message == i) 
                {
                    // return our reply to the user
                    Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"{i}");
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
```

I tried to add some of the currencies in an array and match that with the user input i.e. if userInput in arrayOf Currencies, return currencyRateOfUserInput (sorry i couldnt figure out how to format this)

Im very new to C# so im not sure how many things work, any help how to fix this?? My last resort is to have an if statement for each currency.
P.S Forgive me for any formatting errors or so, first time asking a question on SO

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the full code? Is the current code happening in the controller or in a dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Without a full code posting it's hard to see what you are trying to do ...

```
//if (ActivityTypes.Message == i)
```

If I'm reading your code correctly you are comparing the value of the array ('aud' etc.) to the enum value of ActivityTypes.Message. Thus your code inside the if statement won't execute.

So making some assumptions about your code , try changing the above line to the following :

```
if (activity.Text == i)
```

Should this work , remember to check for culture and lowercase etc.